# Why are the signals that my antenna is receiving weak?

Tags: antenna, hf, arrl, efhw

I recently bought the EFHW antenna kit from ARRL, put it together, and set it up. But, my received signals were not clear enough to hear clearly. Is the problem specific to the antenna from ARRL, my equipment, or I built it incorrectly? I tried every HF band, tried it at daytime, and the lowest point above ground was 1/2 of a foot. When I tuned to the WWV station, I heard nothing. Nothing at all.

Comment: please add some additional specifics: what band were you receiving on? How far off the ground is your antenna installed? what time of day was it?

Comment: What happens when you tune to one of the WWV stations? How is your antenna oriented? Do you have a balun? What is the nature of the transmission line? As it stands, the most reasonable answer seems to be: "you've done something wrong." With such sparse detail on your installation, there isn't an opportunity to help further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because your question doesn’t currently include any information about your specific set up, I can only give you some general tips:

Tune to a known station [such as WWV](https://www.nist.gov/pml/time-and-frequency-division/time-distribution/radio-station-wwv/nist-radio-broadcasts-frequently) so that you can properly calibrate both your station and expectations.

The orientation of your antenna also matters. If the wire is running north to south it will best receive communication east and west. If you are trying to target a particular area make sure the broadside of your antenna faces that direction.